# Force method to run *after* AlertDialog

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog

I'm calling an AlertDialog that exists in a different class. Directly after, I use a callback method to refresh the view. However, it appears the dialog runs on a separate thread, because the callback method gets called *before* the user makes a choice in the AlertDialog, instead of after.

How do I make sure the callback method is only called after the user has made a choice?

```
mClientManager.deleteClientConfirmationDialog ( getActivity (), id );
mCallback.refresh ();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Java noob here.

Comment: if you are a beginner, i suggest you start by reading about java and android. for example, in your case, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Android Dialog's have a method called setOnDismissListener. You set an object with an onDismiss method that is called when the dialog is dismissed. If you don't have access to the Dialog instance being used, your best chance is to just detect when the user comes back from the dialog via onWindowFocusChanged with a true parameter being called on your Activity instance.

Answer (score 0):

> However, it appears the dialog runs on a separate thread

No, it does not.

> because the callback method gets called before the user makes a choice in the AlertDialog, instead of after

The dialog is not being shown until well after `deleteClientConfirmationDialog()` and `refresh()` have been called. You may be *requesting* the dialog to be shown somewhere in there, but all that does it put a message on a queue, to be processed by the main application thread, sometime after you return control of that thread to the framework.

> How do I make sure the callback method is only called after the user has made a choice?

Put the logic in an appropriate event listener. Lance's suggestion of [`setOnDismissListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29) is a reasonable choice, if you want `refresh()` to be called regardless of how or why the dialog is going away.